# Make location.replace() work with form input within javascript keypress event handler

Tags: javascript, html

Goal is to use a `keypress` event handler to take form input and use that input to replace the current page with another using redirect to a new fully qualified URL based partially on the input value. Input is submitted by pressing the Enter key. Keypress event is "handled" correctly but redirect doesn't do anything. I realize I can make this work using 
`<form onsubmit=myfunction()"` 
but would prefer to use an event handler approach for a variety of reasons.

Here is sample HTML/Javascript that demonstrates the problem:

```js
var i_Parent = document.getElementById('inputs');
i_Parent.addEventListener('keypress', handleKeypress, false);

function handleKeypress(e) {
  var id = e.target.id;
  var value = e.target.value;
  var name = e.target.className;
  var node = e.target.nodeName;
  if (node == 'INPUT' && e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('Node=' + node + ' Id=' + id + ' Name=' + name + ' Value=' + value);
    try {
      console.log('In try{}');
      location.replace('https://google.com');
      window.location = 'https://google.com';
      console.log('No exception in try{}');
      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('In catch()');
      return false;
    }
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Appropriate Title Description</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #d9d9d9;
      width: 90vw;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    input[type=number] {
      font-size: 2.8vmin;
      font-family: Arial, verdana;
      width: 3.2em;
      padding: 1px 0px;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      background-color: #5600bb;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Testing Form Input</h2>
  <div id='inputs'>
    <form> Spread =
      <input id='spread' type='number' min='.10' max='2.0' step='.05' , size='4' maxlength='4' value='1.0'> %
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Then why not simply do `form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmitted, false);` I mean, what you try to do is like crossing the river for water, and way more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Yes, I realize that given my simple sample code, this is overkill. Short answer is that I'd prefer to use a general purpose event handler approach for keypress events and another for button press events as I'm under the impression this will be a more versatile approach.

Comment: Well, _keypress_ you use to intercept keys, _onsubmit_ to catch form submission, and in your case you should be looking for the latter. And a more versatile approach is to not complicate things.

Comment: Totally agree and I will likely end up taking your advice for this sample use case. That said, pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the location reassignment isn't working the way I expect in the event handler...

Comment: Is there no server, where you could do all of this?

Comment: @NiLInfinite I'm actually generating the HTML/JS dynamically using AWS lambda code written in Python3 so effectively serverless. This is the reason for the redirect - every time the user changes an input on the page, I want to construct a new URL with the updated query options and replace current page with that new URL. –

Answer (score 0):

an interesting pickle! I think the problem is because you're using the enter key, which by default is submitting the form which reloads the page. If you used a different key it wouldn't be a problem.

I think adding this fixes it (I put it just before the if statement):

```
e.preventDefault();
```

[preventDefault doco here at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

If you add other html controls this might impact them though (I think it would stop space letting you select a checkbox?). So maybe you would only want to do it directly before calling the location.replace

Comment: Thank you, this does cause the the page reassignment to work but seems to have some other side effects in the form. Will experiment with and see if I can make it work. If not, may be time to opt for a simpler approach...

Comment: So, I ended up putting e.preventDefault(); immediately before my try{} block and everything now seems to work as intended!

Comment: Interestingly, the prevent.Default() isn't required when I'm simply changing the parameter content passed to the same base URL. For my use case, since I'm simply replacing the current window.location with a call to a lambda service using modified URL parameters (e.g ?value=123), the e.preventDefault() isn't needed.